# How to subscribe in Meteor to a collection

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor

I have a problem I removed autopublish and now I want to subscribe again to my collections but it does not work ;(

Here is my lib code for the two collections:

```
Events = new Mongo.Collection('events');
Friends = new Mongo.Collection('friends');
```

then my server main.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup



});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("events", function() {
      return events.find();
  })
  Meteor.publish("friends", function() {
      return friends.find();
  })
}
```

and last my client code in the main.js on the client side

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';

Meteor.subscribe("events");
Meteor.subscribe("friends");
```

I am running Meteor 1.4 and my problem is I cant get information from the collection

Here is some code that with the autopublish already worked

```
Template.NeuesEvent.events({
    "submit .add-event": function(event){
        var Name = event.target.name.value;
        var Beschreibung = event.target.beschreibung.value;
        var Datum = event.target.Datum.value;
        var Autor = Meteor.userId();
        var eingeladene = [];
             $.each($('.FreundeCheckbox:checked'), function(){            
                eingeladene.push($(this).val());
            });


        if (Name == "")
        {
            confirm("Das Event braucht einen Namen ;)")
        }
        else {

        Events.insert({
            Name: Name,
            Beschreibung: Beschreibung,
            erstelltAm: new Date(),
            Datum: Datum,
            Eingeladen: eingeladene,
            Autor: Autor
        });

        event.target.name.value = "";
        event.target.beschreibung.value = "";
        FlowRouter.go('/meineEvents');

        return false;
    }
    }
});
```

and the helper to "print" it out

```
Template.meineEvents.helpers({
    event: function(){
        return Events.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    }
});
```

Hope you can help me to modify it so it works again Thanks ;)

Comment: Hopefully you understand what @zim is saying... you should `export` your collections in the same file they are defined, and then `import` them like you do Meteor: `import { Events } from 'relative/path/to/file';`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to reference the symbols, not the collection names, like this:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("events", function() {
      return Events.find();
  })
  Meteor.publish("friends", function() {
      return Friends.find();
  })
}
```

edit:

you said you have these collections:

```
Events = new Mongo.Collection('events');
Friends = new Mongo.Collection('friends');
```

where are they defined? are they available to both client and server? are they under any folder called "/imports"? if so, then they are not eagerly loaded and you need to export/import those symbols.

edit 2:

the next thing to check is to see if the data is published. the easiest way to do that is install meteortoys:allthings (https://atmospherejs.com/meteortoys/allthings) and see if the data made its way to the client. if not, then i would check to ensure that the subscribe() lines you provided are associated with the NeuesEvent template.

i typically do my subscriptions in the template, like this:

```
Template.NeuesEvent.onCreated(function() {
    this.subscribe('events');
    this.subscribe('friends');
});
```

... but it depends on your use case. here, those subscriptions will be active as long as the NeuesEvent template is active. when you switch to a different template, the subscriptions will end.

Comment: might be helpful to note that he should export/import the collections as well

Comment: did not helped ;(

Comment: what do you mean chazsolo?

Comment: @chazsolo, good point, updated my answer to pose relevant questions.

Comment: they are in the lib folder i thaught this folder is on both sides or am i wrong?

Comment: @Michael, it depends on where. if just "/lib", yes that's served to both. but "client/lib" and "server/lib" are not. and if it's "/imports/lib", then that is available to both but not Meteor does not grab those files eagerly, they need to be explicitly exported and imported.

Comment: Now it works my problem was that I subscribed in the main.js and not in the template. Is there a way to do it once for all templates? thanks guys;)

Comment: @Michael, we use a subs manager for such subscriptions. i find it works better if you create a new subs manager for each sub, otherwise it gets confused. https://github.com/kadirahq/subs-manager